# How to override route mechanism in PlayFramework 2.X?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am developing a REST API service using PlayFramework 2.2.1.
For compatibility reasons, I want to add the version of the API levels to the system.

The client sends to the server request with "version" param. The server must read it and choose right controller according with global routes config and given version.

For example, if `version=1`, then Controller must to be chosen from `controllers.v1` package.

All, what I've found in documentation is a custom `Global Settings` class and method `onRequest(Request, Method)` in there. It's good, but I not understand, how to point needed controller class in there. The method is returns an `Action`.

I am a beginner in PlayFramework. What is a right solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a better fit if you use onRouteRequest instead (doc: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/java/play/GlobalSettings.html#onRouteRequest(play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader))

Take a look at this sample from James Roper: http://jazzy.id.au/default/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html . It should give you a better understanding on how to handle your case.